# Spring-Cloud-Stream-Kafka-Binder functional style ignores custom De/Serializer and/or useNativeEncoding?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

We're just upgrading to the 3.0.0-Release of Spring-Cloud-Stream and encounter the following problems:

When using the functional style like this:

```
public class EventProcessor {

    private final PriceValidator priceValidator;

    @Bean
    public Function<Flux<EnrichedValidationRequest>, Flux<ValidationResult>> validate() {
        return enrichedValidationRequestFlux -> enrichedValidationRequestFlux
                .map(ProcessingContext::new)
                .flatMap(priceValidator::validateAndMap);
    }
}
```

The application.yaml looks like this:

```
spring.cloud.stream:
  default-binder: kafka
  kafka:
    binder:
      brokers: ${kafka.broker.prod}
      auto-create-topics: false
  function.definition: validate

# INPUT: enrichedValidationRequests
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.validate-in-0:
  destination: ${kafka.topic.${spring.application.name}.input.enrichedValidationRequests}
  group: ${spring.application.name}.${STAGE:NOT_SET}
  consumer:
    useNativeDecoding: true


spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.validate-in-0:
  consumer:
    configuration:
      key.deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value.deserializer: de.pricevalidator.deserializer.EnrichedValidationRequestDeserializer


# OUTPUT: validationResults
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.validate-out-0:
  destination: validationResultsTmp
  producer:
    useNativeEncoding: true

spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.validate-out-0:
  producer:
    compression.type: lz4
    messageKeyExpression: payload.offerKey
    configuration:
      key.serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value.serializer: de.pricevalidator.serializer.ValidationResultSerializer
```

It seems like the serialization is done twice - when we intercept the messages that get produced in the kafka topic, the consumer would just display them as JSON (strings), but now it's an unreadable byte[]. Also, the downstream consumers in production can't deserialize the messages anymore. Strangely enough, the deserialization of the input messages seems to work just fine, no matter what we put into the consumer properties (either on binder or on default kafka level)
We have a feeling, this bug "is back", but we can't find the exact spot in the code: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1536

Our (ugly) workaround:

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class KafkaMessageConverterConfiguration {

    @ConditionalOnProperty(value = "spring.cloud.stream.default-binder", havingValue = "kafka")
    @Bean
    public MessageConverter validationResultConverter(BinderTypeRegistry binder, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        return new AbstractMessageConverter(MimeType.valueOf("application/json")) {
            @Override
            protected boolean supports(final Class<?> clazz) {
                return ValidationResult.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
            }

            @Override
            protected Object convertToInternal(final Object payload, final MessageHeaders headers, final Object conversionHint) {
                return payload;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Is there a "proper" way of setting the custom serializer or to get the native encoding as it was before?

Comment: Interestingly we have a possibly related proplem when deserializing (in another reactive project that doesn't use the functional style, but the StreamListener approach) and the targetClass in the MappingJackson2MessageConverter.convertFromInternal ends up being a Flux - it should simply return the payload, but of course the payload isn't a Flux, but a different object. Before version 3.0.0, we always included the spring-cloud-stream-reactive dependency, which provided a bean named "MessageChannelToInputFluxParameterAdapter", which did exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

So this was an issue reported right after 3.0.0.RELEASE - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/commit/74aee8102898dbff96a570d2d2624571b259e141. It has been addressed and will be available in 3.0.1.RELEASE (Horsham.SR1) in few days.